Vue: Typescript configuration for non-Vite project
Using Vite in our project is not convenient, beacause we want to use webpack directly. We have set up webpack build and it runs without any issues. But I have a problem with typescript check: it shows an error in the editor:
import { createApp } from "vue"; // error: module '"vue"' has no exported member 'createApp'
import App from "./App.vue"; // I had also error on this line but solved it with shims-vue.d.ts file 

createApp(App).mount("#root");

If I run typescript compilation (tsc) directly in the app folder the output files are generated but I get the error in the terminal.
I thought the issue is related to the TS Server so I've tried restarting it but it didn't help. I've also tried to run vue ts compilation (vue-tsc) but with the same outcome.
My project structure looks like this:
root
|__tsconfig.json
|__ vue-app 
     |__ tsconfig.json

I have two tsconfig files: One for the vue-app and second one in the root for other stuff. In the root tsconfig the vue-app directory is excluded.
tsconfig.json (vue-app):
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vue"],
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": ".out",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

tsconfig.json (root):
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "Node16",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": ".out",
    "strict": true /* enable all strict type-checking options */,
    // aliases declarations:
    "paths": {
      "@core/*": ["./core/*"],
      "@root/*": ["./extension-src/*"]
    },
    // inversify config:
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".vscode-test",
    "**/vue-app/**",
  ]
}

}

Here is the list of deps I've been using:

"@types/vue": "^1.0.31",
"vue": "^3.5.6",


UPDATE:
I've installed @vue/runtime-dom but found out it's not accessible from the vue-app directory. When I remove vue-app from excluded paths in root tsconfig then I can access the @vue/runtime-dom module.

You cannot use tsc with vue because SFCs are not valid js/ts at least. Use vue-tsc if you have to. Also that you use webpack doesn't mean you should use tsc. There are plugins for this. Did you check https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/ ?

I actually don't need to use tsc I used it only as a check to be sure the error shown in the editor is real. But what bothers me is the error shown in the editor. Also I've tried vue-tsc and again: compiled files are generated for all entries but there is the error in the terminal. :-/ As I mentioned, webpack is working fine the configuration is alright (I use VueLoaderPlugin and vue-loader for vue files and babel-loader for ts files).

Yes, it makes sense  to double check IDE problems with vue-tsc. You're missing moduleResolution:bundler or moduleResolution:nodenext in app config. Also no include. I'd suggest to refer vite's config, it's reasonable https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/create-vite/template-vue-ts/tsconfig.app.json

I've tried configuring tsconfig as the vite's but it doesn't solve my problem. I think the issue is probably not related to the tsconfig so I've created a new answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79014313/how-to-setup-vue3-project-without-vite.

Webpack is not involved when you use vue-tsc. If your problem is still that you can't run it then it's a wrong direction

Just to clarify: Webpack build succeeds, but the compilation fails when using both tsc and vue-tsc.

Then the problem is specific to TS config and possibly other things in the project that could affect vue-tsc, and Webpack is irrelevant at this point. To make it clear, you need use vue-tsc, not tsc. tsc can't compile .vue
