How to setup Vue3 project without vite
Past few days I've been struggling with setting up Vue project without vite. The reason why we decided to not use Vite but webpack is this: We are creating VSCode extension and for webviews we only need to build vue code with webpack to javascript, and when using vite the project gets too complex when having multiple webviews. I've managed to setup webpack successfully. The thing I struggle with is an error shown in the editor. First I thought the error is related to typescript configuration so I've asked this question: Vue: Typescript configuration for non-Vite project.
But later I realized that the issue is probably not related to typescript configuration but is hidden somewhere else.
I will start by providing a link to the repo with the minimalistic project: https://github.com/i-m-luke/vue-test.git
What's the issue?
In the src/index.ts I'm getting an error when importing "vue" module:
// index.ts
import { createApp } from "vue"; // error: module '"vue"' has no exported member 'createApp'
import App from "./App.vue"; 

createApp(App).mount("#root");

When I go to imported "vue" reference it gets me to index.d.ts file. However if I do the same thing in a Vite Vue project it gets me to a completely different module (vue.d.mts).
My question:
Does anyone have an idea what could be causing the "wrong" import? I don't understand why I'm not able to access the right "vue" module.

I'm not sure but maybe you could start with the Webpack CLI directly to setup Vue3 nowadays still? Not sure why you would like to stick to the slow and complex Webpack, especially when everyone is migrating towards Vite but you do you. Quite a popular error too, I recommend checking a bit more on the Internet for similar use-cases. You could also have kept the old (now deleted) message tbh, not a big change overall here. Maybe you could even just ignore that error and move along if that's the only issue.

@kissu The reason to not use Vite but webpack is this: We are creating VSCode extension and for webviews we only need to build vue code with webpack to javascript, and using vite the project gets too complex when having multiple webviews. I was thinking about Vue CLI but there is an alert on the page telling it's in maintenance stage and I wasn't sure whether it's working properly. Altough I just used it and after switching the project to ts I get the same error. I could just use ts-ignore to hide the error but then I have to use for every import from vue. I've undeleted the old question.

Not sure how Vite is more complex than Webpack as a whole, quite the opposite but maybe for your specific use case? (still high doubts) It's in maintenance because no modern project should start on something old that no one wants to work with anymore. Like Gulp or Grunt are also deprecated for the same reason. Might just be a TS config/IDE problem then.

Try rsbuild for create vue3 project without vite

Isn't rsbuild for rust? :-O

No, Rsbuild is a high-performance build tool create by Rust, It's provides rich build features, including the compilation of TypeScript, JSX, Sass, Less, CSS Modules, Wasm, and others.
